# Is it haram to say “ I hope you die “ to a person and why?

Tags: halal-haram, dua, death

I know a person who wishes me to die every time we get into a fight and I always tell her that it is haram to say stuff like that can anyone tell me why it’s haram and what are the q consequences of this?